# What is meant by a matrix being strictly positive definite on its range?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Consider the following matrix
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&a_{22}&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&a_{44}&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&a_{55}&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for strictly positive entries $a_{11},a_{22},a_{44}$ and $a_{55}$. Because of the two rows made up entirely of zeros (rows three and four), $A$ is not strictly positive definite. That is to say, it does not hold for all non-zero $\underline{x}\in\mathbb R^6$ that
$\underline{x}^TA\underline{x}>0$. Indeed, the kernel of $A$ is nontrivial with
$$\text{ker}(A)=\left\{\underline{x}\in\mathbb R^6:\underline x=(0,0,x_3,0,0,x_6)^T\right\}.$$
**My problem:** I have come across the phrase of a matrix being "strictly positive definite on *its range*" and want to clarify what is meant by it. We have
$$\text{ran}(A)=\left\{\underline{y}\in\mathbb R^6:\exists\underline{x}\in\mathbb R^6\text{ such that }\,\underline{y}=A\underline{x}\right\}$$
which is comprised precisely of those vectors of the form $\underline y=(y_1,y_2,0,y_4,y_5,0)^T$ where $y_1=a_{11}x_1$ for $x_1\in\mathbb R$, $y_2=a_{22}x_2$ for $x_2\in\mathbb R$, and so on. I see that the sub-matrix formed from the first, second, fourth and fifth rows
$$\tilde{A}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&0&0&0\\
0&a_{22}&0&0\\
0&0&a_{33}&0\\
0&0&0&a_{44}\\\end{pmatrix}$$
is strictly positive definite and corresponds to those non-zero $y_1,y_2,y_3$ and $y_4$ entries in the range for $A$ noted above. Is it true that $A$ is strictly positive definite on it's range, since on neglecting the zero-rows of $A$ we have a strictly positive definite matrix? Is this what is meant by the phrase that the matrix is "strictly positive definite on it's range"?

Comment: It would help to know more about where you encountered this phrase, but, as written, I would take it as: For symmetric $A,$ all $x^TA^3x\geq 0,$ and equals zero only when $Ax=0.$

Comment: But it is unclear if the phrase requires $A$ positive-semidefinite on the whole space as well.

Comment: I agree that it would help to see where you have seen this phrase. Show a screenshot, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive semidefinite with $k<n$ eigenvalues at zero. Assume without loss of generality that $M$ is under the form

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}0_{k\times k} & 0_{k\times(n-k)}\\0_{(n-k)\times k} & M_p\end{bmatrix}$$

where $M_p$ is positive definite. The range is spanned by
$$V=\begin{bmatrix}0_{k\times (n-k)}\\ I_{n-k} \end{bmatrix}.$$

When we say that a positive semidefinite matrix is positive definite on its range, this means that the restriction of the matrix on that subspace in positive definite. In other words, this means that $x^TMx>0$ for all $x\ne0$ in $\mathrm{span}(V)$.

The restriction of $M$ on $\mathrm{span}(V)$, denoted by $M|_V$  is simply given by

$$M|_V = V^TMV=M_p.$$

Comment: This clarifies exactly what I was looking for. Looking at other questions I see this construction $V^{T}MV$ for other choices for the matrices in different contexts. Is this an entirely standard construction for restricting $M$ to a subspace? Is there a reference you have for this construction?

Comment: If you want to restrict a quadratic form $x^TMx$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ on a subspace $S$ spanned by a full-rank matrix $V$ of rank $k<n$, then yes $V^TMV$ is a standard construction. Saying that  $x^TMx>0$ for all $x\ne0$ and $x\in S$ is equivalent to saying that $y^TV^TMVy>0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^k$.